# Dealing with multiple datasets/dataloaders in `pytorch_lightning`

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I'm dealing with multiple datasets training using `pytorch_lightning`. Datasets have different lengths  ---> different number of batches in corresponding `DataLoader`s. For now I tried to keep things separately by using dictionaries, as my ultimate goal is weighting the loss function according to a specific dataset:

```
def train_dataloader(self): #returns a dict of dataloaders
    train_loaders = {}
    for key, value in self.train_dict.items():
        train_loaders[key] = DataLoader(value,
                                        batch_size = self.batch_size,
                                        collate_fn = collate)
    return train_loaders
```

Then, in `training_step()` I do the following:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):        
    total_batch_loss = 0

    for key, value in batch.items():
        anc, pos, neg  = value
        emb_anc = F.normalize(self.forward(anc.x,
                                           anc.edge_index,
                                           anc.weights,
                                           anc.batch,
                                           training=True
                                           ), 2, dim=1)
    
        emb_pos = F.normalize(self.forward(pos.x,
                                           pos.edge_index,
                                           pos.weights,
                                           pos.batch,
                                           training=True
                                           ), 2, dim=1)
    
        emb_neg = F.normalize(self.forward(neg.x,
                                           neg.edge_index,
                                           neg.weights,
                                           neg.batch,
                                           training=True
                                           ), 2, dim=1)
                                
        loss_dataset = LossFunc(emb_anc, emb_pos, emb_neg, anc.y, pos.y, neg.y)
        total_batch_loss += loss_dataset
        
    self.log("Loss", total_batch_loss, prog_bar=True, on_epoch=True)        
    return total_batch_loss
```

The problem is that when the smallest dataset gets exhausted, Lightning will throw a `StopIteration` and so I won't finish training on remaining batches from other datasets. I have considered concatenating everything into a single train `DataLoader` as suggested in the [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.8/multiple_loaders.html) but I don't see how I can weight loss function differently according to this method.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [CombinedLoader](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/api/lightning.pytorch.utilities.combined_loader.html#lightning.pytorch.utilities.combined_loader.CombinedLoader) class and specify `max_size` mode to iterate based on the longest dataloader available.